# Image Processing using ARM?

Tags: image-processing, arm

I'm doing a project on image processing using [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture). I have with me an [AT91SAM9263](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT91SAM) with Linux ported in it. I would like to know what are the image processing libraries which can be used? And what are the other toolsets required?

I'm a newbie in this field.

Comment: Please, clarify, what are you want to do? And what "image processing" do you need? Is there any other software/libraries, you used not on ARM for such task?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look into [ImageMagick's](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) [MagickCore](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php) C library. It has *a lot* of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any image processing libraries you want as long as it is cross compilable. 
Your problem will mostly be the lack of processing power, so everything depends on the resolution and processing you want to do. Some example are

- libpng
- libjpeg
- libtheora

Basically, everything that is using autoconf / automake is crosscompilable. There are some exceptions though. Package using CMake are usually less cross-compilation friendly.

If you are not comfortable with cross-compilation, I suggest you do it once with a simple library, and then to do it with tools like [ptxdist](http://www.pengutronix.de/software/ptxdist/index_en.html) or [scratchbox](http://www.scratchbox.org/)

Comment: Hmm, I thought "Image Processing" is something different than "image format decoding" ;)

Comment: Perhaps, but encoding and decoding includes a fair amount of image processing

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to compile and run [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) on your ARM. It is one of the better free image processing libraries, and (at least up to version 1.0) they did test and run on ARM specifically (when Intel was still manufacturing ARM chips).